# Insert value into a array with hooks (REACT)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have an object I want to add value to the array.

This is my object `{roomType: t, roomName: n, roomColor: c, appliances:[1] }])` I want to add values to the appliances without changing the whole object with hooks.

This is my whole component :

```js
function App(props) {

 

  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([
    {roomType:'bedroom', roomName: "snir", roomColor: "blue"}
  ])

  let NewRoom = (t,n,c) => {
    setRooms([...rooms,{roomType: t, roomName: n, roomColor: c, appliances:[1] }])
  }
  let newAppliances = (a,n) => {
    rooms.map((item) =>{
      if(n === item.name){
        item.appliances.push(a)
      }
      
    })
  }
  console.log(rooms)
  const [indexRoom, setIndexRoom] = useState([])

  let chack = (rIndex,rName,rType) =>{setIndexRoom([rIndex, rName ,rType])}
  






  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path = '/' >
           <Home
             arr = {rooms}
             func = {chack}
          />
          
          </Route>
          <Route  path = '/addroom' render= { (props) =><AddNewRoom add = {NewRoom}{...props}/>}/>


          <Route path = '/room'>

            <Rooms arr = {rooms}
                  index = {indexRoom[0]}
                  name = {indexRoom[1]}
                  type = {indexRoom[2]}
                  funcApp = {newAppliances}
            />

          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    
     
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in newAppliances I want to update the appliances for a room.

Comment: You mentioned an objective but no mention of problem(s) or errors achieving the objective or where specifically you are stuck

Comment: Thank you for mention that, i edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in `newAppliances` method you want to update the appliances for a room,
You can do that by doing the following,

```
let newAppliances = (a,n) => {
    const index = rooms.findIndex(item => item.name === n);
    if(index > -1) {
       if(rooms[index].hasOwnProperty(appliances) && rooms[index].appliances.length > 0) {
           rooms[index].appliances.push(a);  
       }
       else rooms[index].appliances = [a];    
    }
    setRooms([...rooms]);
  }
```

Comment: Can you give me a clue about findIndex?  i mean what is it and what is it for . thank you

Comment: Not working for me,  setRooms didn't update my room's array. any solution?

Comment: `findIndex` is an array method using which you can find then index of an item using complex comparison where the array items are not atomic data like number, string etc.

Comment: Do you see any error in console? It would be better if you could provide with some runnable code like in jsfiddle.

Comment: No error codes in console, its just not adding values. and the code with 8 components and i cant get it all to codePen or something unfortunately.

Comment: Can you console.log(rooms) before the setRooms() method? And see if the appliances are being added in the rooms array?

Comment: Before the setRooms() and after are the same Array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225902/discussion-between-oded-and-sabbir-alam).